# Changing Taskbar menu icon in nodewebkit app dynamically

Tags: notifications, icons, taskbar, node-webkit

I am working on a `nodewebkit` app. Looking for a functionality where in I can change task-bar icon of app to notify users, similar to what `Skype` does when a new message is received by user.
Is there any way it can be done in Nodewebkit?

Initially I tried changing window.icon in package.json file, but then I came to know that it is used only once, i.e. on app load. So that did not work.

Anything else I can try?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you looking for https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window#setbadgelabellabel ?

Comment: Thanks @DhirajBodicherla It Worked for me. Is there any way we can customise that badge label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Window.requestAttention(Boolean attention)` is what I was looking for.
It worked for me.
Thanks to [Dhiraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597441/dhiraj-bodicherla), It gave me an additional feature for icon.